# Custom commandline script: Area code is not set

Tags: magento-2.1, command-line

I've got a module that was written by a 3rd party developer and unfortunately, they've fallen off of the face of the earth. 99% of it works as required, except one issue.
The extension was built to allow a commandline command to be run.

Here is the content of the Module/Console/Now.php file:

```
<?php
namespace dev\UpdatePrice\Console;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use \dev\UpdatePrice\Logger\Logger;
use Magento\Framework\App\State;

class Now extends Command
{
    protected $_logger;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\State $state,
        \dev\UpdatePrice\Logger\Logger $logger
    ) {
        **$state->setAreaCode('frontend');** //<<<<<< THIS IS THE ISSUE
        $name=null;
        $this->_logger = $logger;
        parent::__construct($name);
    }

    protected function configure()
    {
        $this->setName('updateprice:now');
        $this->setDescription('Run Convert Price Now');
    }
    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $convert_helper = $objectManager->create('dev\UpdatePrice\Helper\Data')->UpdatePriceApp(true,"Command Line");
        $this->_logger->info(print_r($convert_helper,true));
    }
}
```

The dev\UpdatePrice\Logger\Logger.php contains:

```
<?php
namespace dev\UpdatePrice\Logger;

class Logger extends \Monolog\Logger
{

}
```

The problem is in the offending line. If I uncomment this line, the command line runs, but then the rest of Magento's commands error out with "Area code already set". I've tried googling solutions to this one, but there is too many possible solutions.

How can I modify this script so that it will run at the command line (or via Cron) without causing errors in the remainder of Magento's command line commands ?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: try to set the area code in the `execute` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to set any area. If need for you, you can set it inside execute method.

**NB: Vendor and Module name start with uppercase**

Try following way:

```
namespace Dev\UpdatePrice\Console;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\State as AppState;

class Now extends Command
{
    protected $_logger;
    public function __construct(
        AppState $appState,
        ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
        \Dev\UpdatePrice\Logger\Logger $logger
    ) {
        $this->appState = $appState;
        $this->objectManager = $objectManager;
        $this->_logger = $logger;
        parent::__construct();
    }

    protected function configure()
    {
        $this->setName('updateprice:now');
        $this->setDescription('Run Convert Price Now');
        parent::configure();
    }
    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        /*$this->appState->setAreaCode('frontend');*/ // If you need then uncomment
        $convert_helper = $this->objectManager->create('Dev\UpdatePrice\Helper\Data')->UpdatePriceApp(true,"Command Line");
        $this->_logger->info(print_r($convert_helper,true));
    }
}
```

Comment: The following is the error I get.

Comment: 'PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to Dev\UpdatePrice\Console\Now::__construct() must implement interface Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface, instance of Dev\UpdatePrice\Logger\Logger given, called in /home/webuser/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 93 and defined in /home/webuser/public_html/app/code/Dev/UpdatePrice/Console/Now.php:14'

Comment: 'Stack trace:
#0 /home/webuser/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(93): Dev\UpdatePrice\Console\Now->__construct(Object(Magento\Framework\App\State), Object(Dev\UpdatePrice\Logger\Logger))
#1 /home/webuser/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(88): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Dev\\Convertp...', Array)
#2 /home/webuser/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(130): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create('Dev\\Convertp...')'

Comment: #3 /h in /home/webuser/public_html/app/code/Dev/UpdatePrice/Console/Now.php on line 14
[webuser@user public_html]$ mag UpdatePrice:now
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to Dev\UpdatePrice\Console\Now::__construct() must implement interface Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface, instance of Dev\UpdatePrice\Logger\Logger given, called in

Comment: /home/webuser/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 93 and defined in /home/webuser/public_html/app/code/Dev/UpdatePrice/Console/Now.php:14
Stack trace:
#0 /home/webuser/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(93): Dev\UpdatePrice\Console\Now->__construct(Object(Magento\Framework\App\State), Object(Dev\UpdatePrice\Logger\Logger))

Comment: #1 /home/webuser/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(88): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Dev\\Convertp...', Array)
#2 /home/webuser/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(130): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create('Dev\\Convertp...')
#3 /h in /home/webuser/public_html/app/code/Dev/UpdatePrice/Console/Now.php on line 14

Comment: Delete var/generation/*